# GCMRegistrar.register issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate Push notifications with android project in Android Studio, using tutorial from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) (even though it's for eclipse).

When i call GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID), nothing happens. I read about this, and maybe it is a problem somewhere in the AndroidManifest. It never goes to onRegister in GCMIntentService class. How to solve this issue?

Here are some parts of the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

            <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

            <uses-permission android:name="xx.xxxxxx.android.jimba.XxXx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

            <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
            <permission
                android:name="xx.xxxxxx.android.jimba.XxXx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <permission
        android:name="xx.xxxxxx.android.jimba.XxXx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="xx.xxxxxx.android.jimba.XxXx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    .
    .
    .
            <activity
                android:name="xx.xxxxxx.android.ActivityLogin"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            </activity>
    .
    .
    .
                <receiver
                    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                        <category android:name="xx.xxxxxx.android" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>

                <service android:name="xx.xxxxxx.android.GCMIntentService" />
```

P.S. I already made one application with push notifications in Eclipse, but this is different project and different IDE, so server side is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you're following is outdated. Use [google's.](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: I know it's outdated but it still works...This project isn't mine and I shouldn't change anything except to implement push notificatons, just like from androidhive tutorial